# Working on a Non-decreasing Color Brightness Sequence

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I'm working on a project at school where one of the things doing is trying to set up a "Non-decreasing Brightness Sequence" method. To explain: I'm being asked to write code that finds and returns the longest sequence of non-decreasing values. For an example, given the following sequence: 67.8, 91.3, **56.3, 87.3, 87.3, 90.4**, 55.0, the sequence that would be returned is the sequence of values shown in boldface. Essentially, I'm being asked to return an array of Line object references—not values—representing this sequence and **I'm having some problems with the program logic and I need help.** This is what I've written so far. the method is being written in the LineSet class of my project:

```
public nonDecrBrightSeq() {
        int maxRow = 1, currentRow = 1 , startIndex = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            double b1 = data[i].brightness();
            double b2 = data[i + 1].brightness();
            if (b1 > b2 && currentRow >= maxRow)
                startIndex = i - currentRow;
            if (b2 < b2 && currentRow <= maxRow)
                startIndex = i + currentRow;
            if (b2 = b2 && currentRow == maxRow)
                startIndex = i + currentRow;
        }
        return currentRow;
    }
```

Also, this is the "brigthness" method that's being substantiated from the "Line" class. The Brightness is calculated based on the red, green, and blue components of a color. The equation I've set up for calculating it is as follows; I was trying to set it up so that that the multiplier isn’t squared, just the R, G, and B values:

```
  public double brightness (Color color) {
        double brightness = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(color.getRed(),2) * .241 + 
                                      Math.pow(color.getGreen(),2) * .691 + 
                                      Math.pow(color.getBlue(),2) * .068);
        return brightness;
    }
```

My instructor gave me a sign hint. He may want me to make this a sorting method, but is it a bubble, selection or insertion or none of the above:

Assume you're posing a challenge to another person.  Tell them you're going to show them a series of playing cards; you'll tell them how many, before showing the first one.  They'll be shown each card, one at a time, and will only see the current card (never the entire series of them).  You hand them a pad and pencil and tell them they can make any notes they'd like.  In the end, they need to tell you the longest non-decreasing sequence of cards, telling you how many cards were in that sequence and what card started the sequence.

If anyone has any insight how I can make the logic of nonDecrBrightSeq better, I would be appreciated. If you need me to show more up my code, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood your question correctly, but I would use this approach:

```
var test = [67.8, 56.3, 87.3, 87.3, 90.4, 55.0, 33, 35, 36, 37, 37, 38, 1, 2, 99];

function findLongestNonDecrSeq(data) {
  var maxLength = 0;
  var currLength = 1;
  var startIndex = 0;
  for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i] < data[i-1]) {
        if (currLength > maxLength) {
        maxLength = currLength;
        startIndex = i - maxLength;
      }
      currLength = 1;
    } else {
      currLength++;
    }
  }
  return {'startIndex':startIndex, 'maxLength': maxLength};
}

var result = findLongestNonDecrSeq(test);
document.write('startIndex: ' + result.startIndex);
document.write('<br>');
document.write('maxLength: ' + result.maxLength);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3Lhrjutu/2/